# Numpy functions mean, max and min giving wrong values in for loop when assigning values in nested list

Tags: python, numpy

`print(l)` gives the right output, but none of the numpy functions do in the first "loop" of the loop.

```
from numpy import mean, max, min


table = [[0] * 3] * 2
for i, l in enumerate([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]):
    print(l)
    table[i][0] = mean(l)
    table[i][1] = max(l)
    table[i][2] = min(l)
print(table)
```

When i run it i get:

[1, 2, 3]

[4, 5, 6]

[[5.0, 6, 4], [5.0, 6, 4]]

Expected:

[1, 2, 3]

[4, 5, 6]

[[2.0, 3, 1], [5.0, 6, 4]]

I suspect something weird is happening with the nested list because i tried `print(mean(l))` (instead of `print(l)`) and that gave the correct mean, but i see no reason for it not working when assigning values to the table.

Comment: `[[0] * 3] * 2` is the wrong way to initialize a nested list.

Comment: `table = [[0] * 3, [0] * 3] ` would work (among other ways ...)